Is it possible to call a python function in javascript for a browser extension?
I'm making an extension for reddit which involves a lot of text processing. There's also a tkinter window where the input data has to be passed to the javascript code. What's the best way to do this? Will the inclusion of python scripts make it harder for other users to run?
Right now I'm working on Mozilla Firefox but I'm planning to localize the extension for chrome too.

Yes using Python for front end operations in a browser extension is not a viable way to do it imo. I think browsers provide tools to display UI elements from an extension when you click on its icon

I mostly need it for back-end tasks. I'm just not sure how to load these python functions in javascript

See nativeMessaging API.
